# Any info on where to get a water sensor with wireless connection

Tags: sensors

Am currently working on my final year project and am in desperate help with a sensor I need a water sensor that can connect wirelessly to a database.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  This is probably actually a better fit for [hardware recs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but we'll see; someone might have valuable input around here. I would, however, recommend you [edit] to be a bit more specific about your requirements for the sensor.  Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to sense? The presence of water? It's temperature? Purity? Depth? Wave motion? The question is rather vague (and probably belongs on h/w recs, as @anonymous2 said)

Comment: Sensor to connect wirelessly to a database, you are missng a few steps there.

Answer (score 2):

**First of all, specify your exact application and question.**

You can buy a simple water sensor like [this](https://www.amazon.in/REES52-REES52_5-Sensor-Droplet-Detection/dp/B018CA9BLI?ref_=fsclp_pl_dp_1) and connect it to a [NodeMCU](https://www.amazon.in/ESP8266-NodeMcu-WiFi-Development-Board/dp/B00UY8C3N0)/[ESP32](https://www.amazon.in/Easy-Electronics-Development-Bluetooth-Consumption/dp/B07TYCFX5C/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=ESP32&qid=1581663096&s=industrial&sr=1-4) or with [Arduino](https://www.amazon.in/Arduino-UNO-R3-Module-Board-Atmega328P/dp/B07X6MTJS4/ref=sr_1_4?crid=KLQ9AVNKI2LO&keywords=arduino%20uno&qid=1581663127&s=industrial&sprefix=Arduino%2Cindustrial%2C298&sr=1-4) + [ESP8266](https://www.amazon.in/REES52-Serial-Wireless-Transceiver-ESP8266/dp/B00O34AGSU/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=ESP8266&qid=1581663150&s=industrial&sr=1-5) and then send your data to the LAN Database in a computer or you can store data on the cloud as simple as [ThingsSpeak](https://thingspeak.com/).

Below are the few examples which shows storing data from Arduino with a sensor to the MySQL Local server, just replace DHT11 sensor with water sensor:

[Arduino Sending Sensor Data to MySQL Server (PHPMYADMIN)](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/embedotronics-technologies/arduino-sending-sensor-data-to-mysql-server-phpmyadmin-a604d4)

[Logging Data to Database Using Arduino Ethernet Shield](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/muhammad-aqib/logging-data-to-database-using-arduino-ethernet-shield-3e9a0e)

[Arduino: Save data to database](https://icreateproject.info/2014/12/14/arduino-save-data-to-database/)